# additional classpath for standalone Neo4j server

Tags: java, neo4j

We want to run a neo4j extension (REST API) which requires external JARs and configurations.

Even though we can add jars to the `{NEO4J_HOME}/plugin/` directory, we want to rely on an already set-up environment including (for example) some `/opt/product/lib/` and `/var/opt/product/conf/` folders.

This is of course super simple when using Embedded Neo4j Server, but how to do the same when using Standalone Neo4j Server ?

Can we do it? by configuration ? by any under-the-hood trick ?

NB: We are using Neo4j v3.2+ which uses the PowerShell scripts to startup.

Answer (score 0):

By editing the `Get-Java.ps1` PowerShell script like this:

```
# Parse Java config settings - Additional ClassPath
$option = (Get-Neo4jSetting -Name 'dbms.jvm.additional.classpath' -Neo4jServer $Neo4jServer)
$ClassPath="$ClassPath;$([System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($option.Value))"
Write-Warning "WARNING: using classpath: $ClassPath";

$ShellArgs = @("-cp `"$($ClassPath)`""`
              ,'-server' `
              ,'-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties' `
              ,'-Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=zip-powershell' `
              ,'-Dorg.neo4j.cluster.logdirectory=data/log' `
              #,'-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y' `
  )
```

And adding following configuration in `neo4j.conf`:

```
#********************************************************************
# JVM Parameters
#********************************************************************

dbms.jvm.additional.classpath=%MY_PRODUCT%/lib/*;%MY_PRODUCT%/conf/*
```

But as mentioned, this requires manual edit of Neo4j PowerShell scripts, which is not much reliable.

Could it be added as a supported option ?